# React Indiana drag scroll component interfering with Ant Design popover

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to implement Ant Design popovers inside a react-indiana-drag-scroll component. I need the popovers to dismiss when the user clicks off them.

When the user clicks anywhere on the page, the active popover disappears. However, If they click inside the scroll component to open another popover or try to scroll the div, the active popover does not dissappear.

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-frog-3mxh7

The above Code Sand Box has the whole scenario to play with, I can also paste the code in if necessary.

Steps to make popup dismiss:
Click one of the "A" cells in the table - the popover should appear.
click on one of the names in the Name column - the popover will dismiss

Steps to make the popover stay:
Click one of the "A" cells in the table - the popover should appear.
Click one of the "A" cells or try to click and drag the table about. - The popover will not disappear

I think that the problem has something do do with the ScrollContainer handling the click event and not letting the browser or antd do anything else with it.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Popover } from "antd";
import ScrollContainer from "react-indiana-drag-scroll";

class GridSquare extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false
  };

  hide = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  handleVisibleChange = visible => {
    this.setState({ visible });
  };

  render() {
    const content = <div>Popup Window</div>;

    return (
      <div>
        <Popover
          content={content}
          title="Title"
          trigger="click"
          placement="right"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
        >
          <a href="none">A</a>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      {
        Name: "Vanessa Smith",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Alan Benedict",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "James Borton",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Belinda Gong",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Barry Homeowner",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Cassandra Blanche",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Carmel Daniels",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Peter Jones",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Grimswick Smith",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Sanrda Martinez",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      },
      {
        Name: "Ronnie Hotdog",
        Things: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="outer-div-constrainer">
        <div className="attendance-floater">
          <table className="table-attendance table table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colSpan="5">Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((row, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{row.Name}</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <ScrollContainer
          className="scroll-container attendance-scroller"
          hideScrollbars={false}
          nativeMobileScroll={true}
        >
          <table className="table-attendance table table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {data[0].Things.map((row, i) => (
                  <th key={i}>Thing</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((row, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  {row.Things.map((i, j) => (
                    <td key={j}>
                      <GridSquare />
                    </td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </ScrollContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```css
.outer-div-constrainer {
  width: 300px;
}

.attendance-scroller {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  direction: rtl;
  cursor: grab;
}
.attendance-floater {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding: 24px"></div>
```

Comment: I checked your code sandbox The popover doesn't seem to appear at all. what are  "A" cells btw? You can copy your code here in case the link becomes dead in future.

Comment: Thanks blueseal. The "A" cells are supposed to be clickable links that pop the popovers up with extra detail for that cell. I have turned them into anchor tags now to make that clearer. You click on the "A" in the cell and the popover appears, the problem is that the first popover does not disappear if you click another popover. If you are still having trouble, let me know what browser you are using and I will investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the developer of `react-indiana-drag-scroll`. The reason of this bug is the unnecessary preventing of the event propagation inside the scroll container event handlers. It's fixed in `1.6.0`. Please update to this version to solve your problem (try at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/for-stackoverflow-udfkt)).

No additional fixes needed.

Comment: Cheers, I'll grab the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I give each [`Popover`](https://ant.design/components/popover/) a unique id, and toggled its `visible` prop based on conditions like `onClick` event in parent `table` and `onStartScroll` in parent `ScrollContainer`. I have also a `activeId` in parent `state` and it only contains one active popover `id` or `null` at a given time.

So, based on `activeId` You can show/hide popovers. But what I noticed is active popover also gets hidden when I click on it.

---

[image: hide-popover-antd]

---

**App**

```
 state = {
    activeId: null
  };

  updateActiveId = id => {
    this.setState({
      activeId: id
    });
  };

  handleOnClick = e => {
    this.setState({
      activeId: null
    });
  };
  handleOnStartScroll = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeId: null
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="outer-div-constrainer">
        <div className="attendance-floater">
          <table className="table-attendance table table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colSpan="5">Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((row, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{row.Name}</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <ScrollContainer
          className="scroll-container attendance-scroller test"
          hideScrollbars={false}
          nativeMobileScroll={true}
          onStartScroll={this.handleOnStartScroll}
        >
          <table
            className="table-attendance table table-condensed"
            onClick={this.handleOnClick}
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {data[0].Things.map((row, i) => (
                  <th key={i}>Thing</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((row, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  {row.Things.map((i, j) => (
                    <td key={j}>
                      <GridSquare
                        id={`${row.Name} ${i}`}
                        activeId={this.state.activeId}
                        updateActiveId={this.updateActiveId}
                      />
                    </td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </ScrollContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**GridSquare**

```
handleVisibleChange = visible => {
    this.props.updateActiveId(visible ? this.props.id : null);
  };

  render() {
    const content = <div>Popup Window</div>;
    return (
      <div className="test">
        <Popover
          content={content}
          title="Title"
          trigger="click"
          placement="right"
          visible={this.props.id === this.props.activeId}
          onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
        >
          <a href="none" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            A
          </a>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60079855-dismiss-popover-react-indiana-drag-scroll).

Note: [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Sorry, I had to switch answers blueseal, your solution was ace but i think now the bug is fixed by the developer I think that is the most pertinent up to date answer. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 0):

please update your version of antd. I updated mine to the latest and it works for me.`^5.11.5` and here's how my popover looks:                            `<Popover placement="bottom" title={<Divider plain>Account</Divider>} content={<PopoverAccount />} trigger="click" autoAdjustOverflow={true}>` try to set the last attribute `autoAdjustOverflow` to true